# How do I copy multiple folders from a remote location to the currently location in Dos

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a folder structure that has a number of subfolders that start with a months and end in a userid. Im wirting a dos batch script to copy all of the folders for the current month

**Example Folder structure**

```
\04_2015_Userid1
\04_2015_Userid2
\04_2015_Userid3
\03_2015_Userid1
\03_2015_Userid2
\03_2015_Userid3
```

The copy should include all the sub files and folders and cannot rely on the date stamp that the file was generated. I looked at the help file for copy but not sure how to tell it to copy folders.

Comment: Are you ***really*** using MS-DOS? Or are you referring to the command line in Windows (which has nothing to do with "MS-DOS")

Answer (score 0):

`xcopy` copies directories recursively.  You can get the current month from

```js
for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list ^| find "="') do set "%%I"
set "month=%LocalDateTime:~4,2%"
set "year=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%"
```

Then to perform the copy, you just

```js
for /d %%I in (%month%_%year%*) do xcopy /I "%%~I" "destination\%%~nI"
```

or similar.